# Sorting a data frame by one column by string and number in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which I want to sort. However, the column I want to sort by is a combination of a letter and a number.

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(paste0("C", 1:20)), b = sample(LETTERS[1:26],20))
df[order(df$a),]
```

Ordering likes this gives me C1, C10, C11, ..., C19, C2, C20, ...

What do I need to change in order to sort the column like this: C1, C2, C3, ...

Thank you. :-)

Comment: What you need is `library(gtools);df[mixedorder(as.character(df$a)),]`

Answer (score 1):

Sorting mixed numeric/character data like this is a common problem.  One option is to continue sorting as text, but to pad every entry with zeroes such that all entries have the same length, e.g  3.  The library `stringr` has a function `str_pad` which can help here:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(paste0("C", str_pad(c(1:20), 3, pad="0"))),
                 b = sample(LETTERS[1:26],20))
df[order(df$a),]

      a b
18 C001 R
11 C002 C
1  C003 O
2  C004 Q
10 C005 I
...
```

## Demo